# failed connection to postgreSQL database created via psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I've created a bunch of databases with a for loop like this:

```
import os
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT

con = psycopg2.connect("user = my_user password = my_password");
con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT);

for txt in list_txt:
    cursor = con.cursor();
    sqlCreateDatabase = "create database " + txt + ";"
    cursor.execute(sqlCreateDatabase);
    cursor.close()
    con.commit()
```

And apparently it works fine because the databases show themselves in the pgAdmin server tree.
After that the connetion fails when I'm trying to reach the databases created thru:

```
db_name = "my_DB"
con_data = "host = localhost dbname = " + db_name + " user = my_user password = my_password"
con = psycopg2.connect(con_data);
cursor = con.cursor();
```

the connections fails, yielding the following OperationalError:

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-a5dcf00c1db0> in <module>
      1 db_name = "my_DB"
      2 con_data = "host = localhost dbname = " + db_name + " user = my_user password = my_password"
----> 3 con = psycopg2.connect(con_data);
      4 cursor = con.cursor();

~\miniconda3\envs\psyco\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    125 
    126     dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
--> 127     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    128     if cursor_factory is not None:
    129         conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory

OperationalError:
```

How can I get to my new databases without create them manually?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the full traceback of the `OperationalError` ?

Comment: You don't need to build the connectionstring by hand. Set up a dict with the needed filds, and use **kwargs instead.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean, @MauriceMeyer. This is the whole text I get when executing the code.

Comment: It works here for me. I could make it fail in which case there was an error message after the second `OperationalError:`. Are you sure yuu have  not cut that out of the above? As to the `**kwargs` suggestion see: [Connect](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect)

Comment: It's done! there was a mistake in the database name generation between upper and lowercases... I close this question. Anyway I thank you all.